# Cannot log in automatically, that is, without asking for the password. Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, gnome, login, 20.04, auto-login

Automatic login does not work, not even for a single user by selecting the check on the installation screen in a newly formatted partition.
Nor have I achieved this by having three users and selecting the button "automatically login" in the menu of a user in Gnome.
A greeting.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you using an Nvidia proprietary driver?  From the release notes: "Automatic login does not work with the NVIDIA proprietary driver (bug 1845801)." 
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-session/+bug/1845801

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answering.

Yes, I have a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti and the Nvidia driver version installed by ubuntu 20.04 is 440.64. I have chosen one of the solutions indicated in the post you refer to:

Remove the splash parameter from the grub so that the line of the file will be: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet" and then update, the commands have been:

sudo nano/etc/default/grub
sudo update-grub

Solved. A greeting.

Comment: should there be a space in `sudo nano/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: @joelb yes, nano is the text editor so the correct line is  
`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`